# Изменение размера спрайт скриптом

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть игровой объект , который по дефолту имеет свой нормальный размер спрайта , но после его замены он приобретает другой размер.
Код которым я заменяю спрайта:

```
GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Sprite2;
```

Как я могу это исправить?
Могу ли я как-то подогнать спрайт которым я заменю под размер предыдущего.

Comment: Либо менять `transform.localScale`, либо в импорте спрайтов поставить им разное значение **Pixels per unit**, что предпочтительнее на мой взгляд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто поясню. Существует два различных способа нарисовать спрайт - `SpriteRenderer` и `Image`(для UI). Опишу вам очень грубо, как они работают:

[`SpriteRenderer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-SpriteRenderer.html) - берёт ваш спрайт, смотрит на его разрешение, затем делит его на `Pixels Per Unit`, которые указаны в спрайте (выделите спрайт в проекте и увидите этот параметр). Получив кол-во юнитов по вертикали и горизонтали, которое должен занимать спрайт - рисует его этого размера.

[`Image`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/script-Image.html) - все элементы UI используют компонент `RectTransform`, вместо обычного Transform. Отличие в том, что  `RectTransform` помимо позиции, скейла и поворота имеет ещё и размер. Поэтому Image вместо того, чтобы считать сколько юнитов должен занимать Sprite просто рисует его в том размере, который указан в RectTransform объекта на котором висит Image.

Грубо говоря - первый сам считает исходя из Sprite-а какого размера он должен быть, а второй просто фигачит в уже имеющийся свой размер.

Если вы хотите изменить размер первого, как вам уже подсказали, меняйте параметр `Pixels Per Unit`, если второго - меняйте размер объекта через `RectTransform`.